# Sign in to ClearDB with a Windows Azure Account

Tags: azure, cleardb

Usually we log into our ClearDB account through the Microsoft Azure interface. We find the database within Azure interface, click on it, and are automatically signed-in to ClearDB. How can we sign into ClearDB without going through the Azure interface?